# TPDFImage.LoadFromFile makes printer screen show up and cuts off the rest of the function's execution

Tags: delphi, pdf, jpeg

I am aiming to convert a PDF to JPEG, so I can show it in an image viewer that is embedded in my Delphi program. Here is the code for my function:

```
function TAnexo.loadFilePdf(AFile:String): Boolean;
Var FPicture:TPDFImage;
    FStream: TMemoryStream;
    PdfExist: Boolean;
    jpeg: TJPEGImage;
begin
  result := false;
  PdfExist := fileExists(AFile);
  if PdfExist then
  begin
    fResultFileNameBmp := AFile + '.jpg';
    FPicture:=TPDFImage.Create;
    Try
      //set resolution and page before load so the first requested page is loaded
      FPicture.Resolution:=300;
      FPicture.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
      FPicture.CurrentPage:=1;
      FPicture.LoadFromFile(AFile);
      jpeg := TJPEGImage.Create;
      try
        jpeg.CompressionQuality := 100;
        jpeg.PixelFormat := jf24Bit;
        jpeg.Scale := jsFullSize;
        jpeg.Performance := jpBestQuality;
        jpeg.GrayScale := False; {Apenas tons de cinza}
        jpeg.ProgressiveDisplay := False; {Display Progressivo}
        jpeg.Assign(FPicture);
        jpeg.SaveToFile(fResultFileNameBmp);
      finally
        jpeg.Free;
      end;
      self.loadFileToBinary(fResultFileNameBmp);
    finally
      FPicture.Free;
      DeleteFile(fResultFileNameBmp);
      DeleteFile(AFile);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

But when the function reaches the line "FPicture.LoadFromFile(AFile);", it shows a screen requesting that I choose between the available printers to print the PDF and, no matter what I choose, the rest of the function will not execute.

[printer screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfZ5X.png)

What could be the solution? My intention is not to print the PDF, but only to make de PDF-JPEG conversion behind the scenes so I can visualize it in the image viewer whenever I would like.

Edit: Aparently there's another line responsible for making the printer dialog show up in my program. I have an instance of TChromium calling the PrintToPdf() function before my custom function executes, but I still don't know how to make my instance of TChromium save the PDF without bringing up the printer dialog. Here's the code where it executes:

```
procedure TfrmDarfOnline.actConfirmarExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Self.fDarfAvulso.FilePdf := ArquivoPDF{my PDF file's path};
  Self.fDarfAvulso.Chrome.PrintToPDF(Self.fDarfAvulso.FilePdf,'DARF',Self.Chrome.Browser.MainFrame.GetURL);
  sleep(2000);
  Chrome.ClearCache;
  Chrome.DeleteCookies('http://www31.receita.fazenda.gov.br');
  inherited;
  ModalResult := mrOk;
end;
```

Comment: Where does `TPDFImage` come from? [ITF Ingenieurbüro](https://www.itf-it.de/tpdfimage-1-5/)?

Comment: @AmigoJack yes.